# How to optimize this bufferedimage loop?

Tags: java, image, loops, image-processing, optimization

**I'm using the following loop to calculate the difference between two images of the same size:**

```
static double calculateError(BufferedImage canvas, BufferedImage ideal) {
    double error = 0.0D;

    for (int x = 0; x < Polygonizer.WIDTH; x++) {
      for (int y = 0; y < Polygonizer.HEIGHT; y++) {
        Color c1 = new Color(canvas.getRGB(x, y));
        Color c2 = new Color(ideal.getRGB(x, y));

        error += Math.abs(c1.getRed() - c2.getRed());
        error += Math.abs(c1.getGreen() - c2.getGreen());
        error += Math.abs(c1.getBlue() - c2.getBlue());
      } 
    } 
    return error;
  }
```

It works fine but rather slow, and I have no idea how to make it go faster.


I've already tried using `ExecutorService` to no good and I could use some advice.

---

Edit: Thanks, everyone. Here's the optimized version:

```
private static int APPROXIMATION = 1;

private static int[] idealData;

public static final void setIdeal(BufferedImage ideal) {
        int[] rawData = ((DataBufferInt)ideal.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        idealData = new int[rawData.length * 3];

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < rawData.length * 3; i += 3) {
            idealData[i]     = (rawData[counter]       & 0xFF);
            idealData[i + 1] = (rawData[counter] >> 8  & 0xFF);
            idealData[i + 2] = (rawData[counter] >> 16 & 0xFF);

            counter++;
        }
    }

    static double calculateError(BufferedImage canvas) {
        long error = 0;

        final int[] canvasData = ((DataBufferInt)canvas.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < canvasData.length; i += APPROXIMATION) {
            error += Math.abs((canvasData[i]       & 0xFF) - (idealData[counter]));
            error += Math.abs((canvasData[i] >>  8 & 0xFF) - (idealData[counter + 1]));
            error += Math.abs((canvasData[i] >> 16 & 0xFF) - (idealData[counter + 2]));

            counter += 3 * APPROXIMATION;
        }

        return error;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `double` to accumulate integer values

Comment: In your optimized version: Why use a `counter` when you have `i` and they always have the same value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of the `BufferedImage`s, for example because you instantiated them with the constructor, there's an even faster way.

If the `BufferedImage`s are of type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, do this:

```
byte[] canvasData = ((DataBufferByte)canvas.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
byte[] idealData  = ((DataBufferByte)ideal .getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

int error = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < canvasData.length; i++) {
    error += Math.abs((canvasData[i] & 0xFF) - (idealData[i] & 0xFF));
}
```

If the `BufferedImage`s are of type `TYPE_INT_RGB`, do this:

```
int[] canvasData = ((DataBufferInt)canvas.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
int[] idealData  = ((DataBufferInt)ideal .getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

int error = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < canvasData.length; i++) {
    error += Math.abs((canvasData[i]       & 0xFF) - (idealData[i]       & 0xFF));
    error += Math.abs((canvasData[i] >>  8 & 0xFF) - (idealData[i] >>  8 & 0xFF));
    error += Math.abs((canvasData[i] >> 16 & 0xFF) - (idealData[i] >> 16 & 0xFF));
}
```

(disclaimer: Untested code, but something I've done often enough that I'm confident)

Comment: Your solution is the best by far, blazingly fast.

Comment: The methods `getRGB` and variants do some color space conversion, even if all color spaces are the same. While doing that, they allocate small arrays and whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

You create two instances of `Color` per point, that's quite a bit. There's a much faster way of extracting the RGB from an int (look at the sources of `Color`).

More importantly, you extract points one by one, which is usually terribly slow (as they may be organized differently in the `BufferedImage`s). Call a method extracting more of them at once into an `int[]`.

AFAIK there's a way to let the image compute the result, which is probably still faster.

> I've already tried using `ExecutorService` to no good and I could really use some advice.

This should also help, but only up to the number of cores you have. However, using paralel streams is usually much simpler. But that's a different story (question).

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will redo the loop tomorrow taking your tips into account.